# Set the language for a single program execution

Tags: environment-variables, locale

[Complete C++ i18n gettext() “hello world” example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003360/complete-c-i18n-gettext-hello-world-example/1033337#1033337) sets the LANG environment variable using export before executing the program (Linux):

```
export LANG=es_MX.utf8
./hellogt
```

Is there a way to set the language just while executing hellogt, like a command line argument?
This would be handy for testing programs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In ksh, bash, and similar shells,

```
LANG=es_MX.utf8 ./hellogt
```

will set `LANG=es_MX.utf8` only for the invocation of `./hellogt`.

More portably, there is a program called `env`

```
env LANG=es_MX.utf8 ./hellogt
```

which will set environment variables and run the program specified.  This works in all shells, including `csh` and traditional `sh` (which do not support the first method).

Answer (score 8):

You mean something like:

```
LANG=es_MX.utf8 ./hellogt
```

?  Or maybe you mean you want to parse the commandline (argv), find the language passed in, and pass it to setlocale?

Comment: For testing programs so without modifying the code.

Comment: So, the first one.